# Javascript изменение свойств div выведенного в PHP

Tags: php, javascript

На странице имеются блоки видео div, размер которых задается с помощью Javascript функций, а так же по верх накладывается картинка, которая загружается с youtube. Хочу переделать, что бы ссылки на видео грузились с базы данных MySQL. В следствии попыток div создается, но там ничего не отображается.
Вот рабочий вариант:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $(".youtube").each(function() {
            // Based on the YouTube ID, we can easily find the thumbnail image
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(http://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + this.id + '/sddefault.jpg)');

            // Overlay the Play icon to make it look like a video player
            $(this).append($('<div/>', {'class': 'play'}));

            $(document).delegate('#'+this.id, 'click', function() {
                // Create an iFrame with autoplay set to true
                var iframe_url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.id + "?autoplay=1&autohide=1";
                if ($(this).data('params')) iframe_url+='&'+$(this).data('params');

                // The height and width of the iFrame should be the same as parent
                var iframe = $('<iframe/>', {'frameborder': '0', 'src': iframe_url, 'width': $(this).width(), 'height': $(this).height() })

                // Replace the YouTube thumbnail with YouTube HTML5 Player
                $(this).replaceWith(iframe);
            });
        });
     });
     </script>
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var ad = $(".media").width();
        var as = $(".youtube").width(ad); 
        var ay = $(".youtube").height(ad/2);
        var az = $("iframe").width(ad); 
        var aq = $("iframe").height(ad/2);
     $(window).resize(function() {
        var ad = $(".media").width();
        var as = $(".youtube").width(ad); 
        var ay = $(".youtube").height(ad/2);
        var az = $("iframe").width(ad); 
        var aq = $("iframe").height(ad/2);
    });

    });
    </script>
 <link href="css/video.css"
          rel="stylesheet" >

<div class="container"> 
<div class="youtube"
     id="fsrJWUVoXeM" 
     >
</div>

<div class="youtube" 
     id="lR4tJr7sMPM" 
     >
</div>

<div class="youtube" 
     id="XcyARPJFVi8" 
     >
</div>
</div>
```

СSS:

```
 .youtube {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 200ms ease-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

.youtube .play {
    background: url("https://www.youtube.com/yt/brand/media/image/YouTube-icon-dark.png") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 64px 48px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: .8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.youtube .play:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

iframe {
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

.media{
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

Попытка переделать:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#block").load('index.php');
  }); 
  </script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".youtube").each(function() {
        // Based on the YouTube ID, we can easily find the thumbnail image
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(http://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + this.id + '/sddefault.jpg)');

        // Overlay the Play icon to make it look like a video player
        $(this).append($('<div/>', {'class': 'play'}));

        $(document).delegate('#'+this.id, 'click', function() {
            // Create an iFrame with autoplay set to true
            var iframe_url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.id + "?autoplay=1&autohide=1";
            if ($(this).data('params')) iframe_url+='&'+$(this).data('params');

            // The height and width of the iFrame should be the same as parent
            var iframe = $('<iframe/>', {'frameborder': '0', 'src': iframe_url, 'width': $(this).width(), 'height': $(this).height() })

            // Replace the YouTube thumbnail with YouTube HTML5 Player
            $(this).replaceWith(iframe);
        });
    });
 });
 </script>
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var ad = $(".media").width();
        var as = $(".youtube").width(ad); 
        var ay = $(".youtube").height(ad/2);
        var az = $("iframe").width(ad); 
        var aq = $("iframe").height(ad/2);
     $(window).resize(function() {
        var ad = $(".media").width();
        var as = $(".youtube").width(ad); 
        var ay = $(".youtube").height(ad/2);
        var az = $("iframe").width(ad); 
        var aq = $("iframe").height(ad/2);
    });

    });
    </script>

 <link href="css/video.css"
          rel="stylesheet" >

<div id="block"> 
</div>
```

PHP:

```
   if(! $conn )
   {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   mysql_select_db('league');

   $sqls = "SELECT * FROM media";
   $results = mysql_query($sqls, $conn);

   while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
       echo $rows[1];
       echo '<div class="youtube" id="XcyARPJFV"></div>';
   }

   echo "Entered data successfully\n";
?>
```

К базе данных подключается нормально, данные передаются: в инспекторе видны div с заданным class и id, но блоки нормально не отображаются.

P.S.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#block").load('index.php', function() {
      $(".youtube").each(function() {
        // Based on the YouTube ID, we can easily find the thumbnail image
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(http://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + this.id + '/sddefault.jpg)');

        // Overlay the Play icon to make it look like a video player
        $(this).append($('<div/>', {'class': 'play'}));

        $(document).delegate('#'+this.id, 'click', function() {
            // Create an iFrame with autoplay set to true
            var iframe_url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.id + "?autoplay=1&autohide=1";
            if ($(this).data('params')) iframe_url+='&'+$(this).data('params');

            // The height and width of the iFrame should be the same as parent
            var iframe = $('<iframe/>', {'frameborder': '0', 'src': iframe_url, 'width': $(this).width(), 'height': $(this).height() })

            // Replace the YouTube thumbnail with YouTube HTML5 Player
            $(this).replaceWith(iframe);
        });
      });
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var ad = $(".media").width();
        var as = $(".youtube").width(ad); 
        var ay = $(".youtube").height(ad/2);
        var az = $("iframe").width(ad); 
        var aq = $("iframe").height(ad/2);
     $(window).resize(function() {
        var ad = $(".media").width();
        var as = $(".youtube").width(ad); 
        var ay = $(".youtube").height(ad/2);
        var az = $("iframe").width(ad); 
        var aq = $("iframe").height(ad/2);
    });

    });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас загрузка `$("#block").load('index.php');` (Это асинхронный запрос ...) выполняется позже, чем `$(".youtube").each(function() { ... });`

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#block").load('index.php', function() {
      $(".youtube").each(function() {
        // Based on the YouTube ID, we can easily find the thumbnail image
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(http://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + this.id + '/sddefault.jpg)');

        // Overlay the Play icon to make it look like a video player
        $(this).append($('<div/>', {'class': 'play'}));

        $(document).delegate('#'+this.id, 'click', function() {
            // Create an iFrame with autoplay set to true
            var iframe_url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.id + "?autoplay=1&autohide=1";
            if ($(this).data('params')) iframe_url+='&'+$(this).data('params');

            // The height and width of the iFrame should be the same as parent
            var iframe = $('<iframe/>', {'frameborder': '0', 'src': iframe_url, 'width': $(this).width(), 'height': $(this).height() })

            // Replace the YouTube thumbnail with YouTube HTML5 Player
            $(this).replaceWith(iframe);
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Забыл добавить функцию смены размера, можете подсказать как быть  с учетом еще тех функций? Как запрос составить?

Comment: После прохождения цикла `$(".youtube").each(function() { ... });`

Comment: Добавил в P.S. как сформулировал запрос. Оно показывает блоки, но не отображает картинки, и при клике ошибка открытия видео.

Comment: После прохождения цикла, а не в сам цикл ...

Comment: Перенес функции после цикла, результат такой же: блоки с нужными id и class, но картинки не подгружаются, и ошибка при попытки проиграть.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало.